# Почему бесконечный while (true) рано или поздно прекращает работать?

Tags: php

Мне необходимо выполнять скрипт без остановок, мой скрипт может работать 1, 2 или 3 часа, но потом прекращает работу, что не так? Как исправить?

```
<?php

while (true){

$json = file_get_contents("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", false, stream_context_create(['http' => ['ignore_errors' => true]]));

//получены все данные

if($http_response_header[0] !== 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){

print 'ОШИБКА. ПОВТОРЮ ПОПЫТКУ ЧЕРЕЗ 5 СЕКУНД';

sleep(5);

continue;//???????????? 

}   


$data = json_decode($json, true); 


foreach($data as $values) {

$id = $values['id'];

file_get_contents("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js?igogo=$id", false, stream_context_create(['http' => ['ignore_errors' => true]]));

//обрабатываю каждый ранее полученный id из первого file_get_contents

if($http_response_header[0] !== 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') continue;
  
    
$sym = strtolower($values['Date']);
print $sym;

sleep(3);

}


}
```

Скрипт проверяет ответ сервера и если он 200 ок идет дальше в foreach цикл, где так же проверяет ответ сервера, если он не 200 ок идет дальше проверять новый url - continue...

По завершению работы скрипта, он по новой стартует и занаво проверяется первый url и если все ок, уходит в цикл. Если не 200 ок показывает ошибку и рестартует через 5 секунд.

Вроде бы все работает, но спустя час-два скрипт завершается где-то в центре выполнения foreach. В php.ini все что можно было увеличено или настроено на безлимитное выполнение.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Спасибо!

p.s. url указаны просто для наглядности.

Comment: Я в своём проекте использовал react/event-loop для зацикливания скрипта. Дополнительно добавил в cron скрипт, который перезапускает первый, если тот внезапно умер. Не уверен, правда, что вы потянете такой способ

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите логи. Там всё написано. Скорее всего скрипт просто отваливается с ошибкой, например не смог прочитать данные с `url` или ошибка разбора данных или stackoverflow, да ещё куча причин. Если нет в логах, то оборачивайте в try/catch и в catch пишите в лог и смотрите причину

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю логи на сервере.